# Impala Query Performance

Tags: impala

I am running on a POC environment where there are only one name node and one data node running. Impala daemon is running on data node. Both of the nodes have 128GB memory each. I had set the mem_limit to 60GB.

I had two big tables in Impala. First table has around 635 million records while second table is around 250000 records. I inner join this 2 tables using a common parameter. The SQL statement is as the following:

```
select a.*, b.* from table_a a inner join table_b b on a.param=b.param order by a.t_date desc
```

When i use **EXPLAIN**, it showed **Estimated Per-Host Requirements: Memory=992.03MB VCores=2**. When i run this query, it took more than one hour and the result yet to be return. I am wondering why it took so long. Is this related to mem_limit settings? How can i tune such query?

Answer (score 2):

Try tuning as [Impala performance](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_performance.html)

Some ideal

- Try `big_table` join `small_table`
- Partition on param column
- If have many
  query execute in the same time, you should enable Admission
  controll (2) and Dynamic Resource Pools (3)
- Try execute `summary` after execute your query in impala-shell to see what step take long time.
- And plz post all result of EXPLAIN statement

P/S: Sorry because im not enough reputation to post more than 2 link